# Where's Oleaut32.lib in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, .lib

I need Oleaut32.lib in order to use SysAllocString C++ function but I can't find it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system (W7 x64) this lib is stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib. If your question was 'where on the Internet is this file', the answer is 'Windows SDK', which can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24826.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't found it using Start Menu search option :)